# Why my error occurs after defining @layer components and @apply in tailwind css?

Tags: tailwind-css

I am learning tailwind CSS. When I cut the classes from **index.html** and paste it into the CSS file it throws an error.  CSS file has

```
@tailwind base;


@tailwind components;


@tailwind utilities; 

    
@layer components {
    .btn {
        @apply inline-block px-5 py-3 rounded-lg shadow-lg bg-indigo-500 hover:bg-indigo-400 hover:-translate-y-0.5 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:ring-opacity-50 focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:ring-offset-2 active:bg-indigo-600 transform transition text-white uppercase tracking-wider font-semibold text-sm sm:text-base
    }
}
```

Any suggestion for this. Front UI error Image is
[image]

Comment: can you share your tailwind version and tailwind config? seems to work fine for me on https://play.tailwindcss.com/eiichF5fzv

Comment: {
  "name": "tailwind",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.4",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.2.19",
    "vite": "^2.6.14"
  }
}

Comment: tailwind config ` module.exports = {
  purge: [],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {
      backgroungColor: ["active"],
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
`

Comment: play.tailwindcss.com/eiichF5fzv  --------------> It works fine from the tailwind play. But not working on my laptop.

Answer (score 1):

You have a spelling error in `tailwind.config.js`, its`backgroundColor`, not `backgroungColor`

```js
module.exports = {
  purge: [],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: { extend: {} },
  variants: { extend: { backgroundColor: ["active"] } },
  plugins: [],
};
```